# Difference between CHAR & NCHAR in database WITH UTF-8 collation

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, sqlanywhere

In the SAP SQL Anywhere (where datatypes and most of the structures are very similar to SQL Server) the default database collation is set to UTF-8 - settings in detail below:

[image]

I have a set of special characters which the database needs to store and work with (*range: U+1400 - U+167F*) and after the test insert both `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` datatypes were able to accommodate for these special characters with no visible difference (except the allocated space) - see below:

[image]

Do I understand correctly when DB collation is set to UTF-8 (with UTF8BIN charset) the `CHAR/VARCHAR` datatype is by default able to store UTF-8 charset and `NCHAR/NVARCHAR` the UTF-16? Meaning, I do not have to convert all `CHAR/VARCHAR` objects into `NCHAR/NVARCHAR` if all I need is the UTF-8 range: U+1400 - U+167F ?

Comment: Note: UTF-8 and UTF-16 are character _encodings_, both for the full range of codepoints in the Unicode character _set_. The term "charset" usually means character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer my own question:**

Yes, CHAR and VARCHAR in UTF-8 Collation will store all characters but the datatype lenght specification will differ. When defining varchar lenght e.g.: VARCHAR(100) we expect 100 character string limit. This will only work for the characters where 1char = 1byte (ASCII), for all UTF-8 characters (2-4bytes) the number will specify the byte-lenght e.g.: VARCHAR(100) will be able to contain only UTF-8 string which is 25 characters long for 4-byte UTF-8 text.

Please feel free to correct me or improve my answer.

Comment: Not bytes really, but UTF-8 code units, which are one byte each. Similarly, a UTF-16 datatype counts UTF-16 code units. (`NVARCHAR(100)` stores up to 50 to 100 Unicode codepoints).